# Parsing a Multidimensional array from php to Javascript via json

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to send an array from php to javascript through ajax and am having some troubles.

My php array code looks something like this:

```
if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'miniCart'){
  foreach($_SESSION['cart']['items'] as $item){
    $message[$item['id']]['name'] = $item['name'];
    $message[$item['id']]['price'] = number_format($item['price'], 2, '.', '');
    $message[$item['id']]['qty'] = $item['count'];
  }
    $message = json_encode($message,true);
}
```

And this builds an array that looks something like this:

```
[2] =>
     [name] => "Product 1"
     [price] => "$15.00"
     [qty] => "2"
[1] =>
     [name] => "Product 2"
     [price] => "$15.00"
     [qty] => "3"
```

My JS code looks something like this:

```
var miniCart = function () {
    $(".tester").on("click", function(event) {
    var action = 'miniCart';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cart/cart.php",
            data:"action=" + action + "&ajax=true",
            success: function(string){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(string);
                alert( obj.name);

        }});
    }); 
}
```

My Json that is sent from php to JS looks like this:

```
{“2”:{“name”:”Product 1”,”price”:”15.00”,”qty”:”3”},”1”:{“name”:”Product 2”,”Price”:”15.00”,”qty”:”3”}}
```

I understand that this wont work, if someone can help finish this so that I can construct another array on the JS side that would be most helpful.  My problem is that I can't parse them out correctly.  I have tried many variations of JSON parsing but I think the "2" in the beginning is throwing it off.  The item ID will never always be changing depending upon the order.

Perhaps I'm trying to engineer this incorrectly.  I ultimately want to use these variables to build a shopping cart table.

Please assist.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: The json code you posted is the same as the php array of object created, can you please explain more, if the problem is that the json is an array which is not sorted (starting with index 2), the php array starts also with the index 2 ... could you please explain more what is the problem ?

Comment: if that is the actual json output, then it wont work as those are the wrong type of quotes: `“”` should be like `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And this builds an array that looks something like this:

You're actually building an **associative** array in PHP, not a 0-indexed array. It then gets converted into a JSON object (with item IDs as keys), not a JSON array.

To get the name of the item with ID "2" in javascript:

```
alert(obj["2"].name);
```

You can iterate over the JSON object like this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log("Item ID: " + key);
    console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

Comment: Thank Sylvain for your response.  This has pointed me in the right direction, however I have a question.  How do I iterate through the associative array if I don't know the name of it?  In this example "2".      alert(obj[??].name);

Comment: I've edited my answer which shows how to iterate over the javascript `obj` variable,